# Jquery Simple Slider should show values with decimal point and without decimal point

Tags: jquery, slider, decimal-point

I am using two slider from the following link [https://github.com/loopj/jquery-simple-slider]. The first one should show decimal points and the second one should not show decimal points.

This is my html code.

```
<input  type="text" id="first" name="first" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-step="1" /><span></span><span class="output">0</span>
<input  type="text" id="second" name="second" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-step="1" /><span></span><span class="output">0</span>
```

This is my script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="simple-slider.js"></script>
<link href="simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="simple-slider-volume.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<script>
$(function () {
        $("[data-slider]")
                .each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    $("<span>")
                            .insertAfter($(this));
                })
                .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
                    $(this)
                            .nextAll(".output:first")
                            .html(data.value.toFixed(1));
    });
     });
</script>
```

But both of them is showing decimal points. To not show the decimal points I added html(data.value.toFixed(0)) at the end, but this applies to both of them. So I created a new simple-slider.js and named it as predata_simple-slider.js and changed the data-slider values to predata-slider.

This is how I have changed the code in html.

```
<input  type="text" id="first" name="first" value="" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-step="1" /><span></span><span class="output">0</span>
<input  type="text" id="second" name="second" value="" predata-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-highlight="true" data-slider-step="1" /><span></span><span class="output">0</span>
```

script :

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("[data-slider]")
                .each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    $("<span>")
                            .insertAfter($(this));
                })
                .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
                    $(this)
                            .nextAll(".output:first")
                            .html(data.value.toFixed(1));
    });
     });
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $("[predata-slider]")
                .each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    $("<span>")
                            .insertAfter($(this));
                })
                .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
                    $(this)
                            .nextAll(".output:first")
                            .html(data.value.toFixed(1));
    });
     });
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="simple-slider.js"></script>
<script src="predata-simple-slider.js"></script>
<link href="simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="simple-slider-volume.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But I need to know how to do that in a single script?

Thanks in advance.